# Output using 2 conditions, second condition will use one of 2 different formulas

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently trying to make this formula using `IF`/`IFS` , `AND`
currently looks like this: `=IF((D7=Yes)AND(C7>2500),C7*E5)`
so I am trying to check for 2 conditions

1. I have a cell that has a "yes, no" pull down. So it is checking for a yes

   - if it is yes then it should check if another cell is less than 2500.

If it is >2500, then a specific formula should be used `(C7*E5)`

If it was <2500, then it would use a different formula (basically the same, just `E5` would be `F%`, fulling from a different number.

I am not sure if I am on the right track at all.

I have tried using `AND`, `IF`, `IFS`. I am sure I am close but not doing the right combo.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you do it:

```
=IF(AND(D7="Yes"; C7>2500); C7*E5; C7*F5)
```

unless you want it like this:

```
=IF(D7="Yes"; IF(C7>2500; C7*E5; C7*F5); )
```